# Is there an equational theory which has non-trivial finite models but no infinite model?

Tags: universal-algebra

This is a dual question to my previous question, here: [Is there an equational theory which has infinite models but no non-trivial finite models?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434643/is-there-an-equational-theory-which-has-infinite-models-but-no-non-trivial-finit). My current question is, does there exist an algebraic signature $\Omega$ and an equational theory $T$ of $\Omega$ such that $T$ has non-trivial finite models, but no infinite model? Non-trivial means cardinality greater than $1$.

Comment: No. Equational theories are closed under direct products of arbitrary index.

Comment: @Eran That should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is one result from universal algebra that you should know it is this:

A class of algebraic structures is an equational class if and only if it is closed under homomorphic images, subalgebras, and direct products (with arbitrary index).

Using this, let $\mathbf{A}$ be an algebraic structure with $\vert A\vert>1$. Choose your favorite infinite set $I$. Then $\displaystyle\Pi_{i\in I}\mathbf{A}$ satisfies the same equational identities as $\mathbf{A}$ and is infinite.

The original source for this result is

Birkhoff, Garrett. "On the structure of abstract algebras." Proceedings of the Cambridge Philosophical Society. 1935.